# SendInput required delay between characters on website

Tags: javascript, c#, winapi, automation

I want to write a para with help of SendInput WinApi. I have written code as per requirement and it is working fine. I have tested all characters on notepad or any application and it is working fine. Also if textbox which has not event (ie. keyup or keydown) in website than also it is working fine. All above cases I have not put any delay between para keys.

But I am facing weird issue when a textbox which has event like onKeyUp or ajax call on textchange event on website, SendIput misses some characters, so I have to put delay between keys.

I am curious about why this delay required for above.. Anyone have idea about it?

Comment: Are you using keyup event?

Comment: yes @chandil03 I used keyup event on textbox of website

Comment: can you post that code snippet?